# PASS ImagevIew Array to Bitmap Android

Tags: java, android

How to pass the imageview array to the following code

IMage view array

```
private Integer[] Imgid = {
            R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3,
            R.drawable.pic4,
    };

    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),**R.drawable.pic1[]???**);
```

Comment: so what exactly u want to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an `Bitmap` array and you have run a loop to put `drawable` into bitmaps like this :

```
private Integer[] Imgid = {
            R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3,
            R.drawable.pic4,
    };
    Bitmap bitmapOrg[];
    for (int i = 0; i < Imgid.length; i++) {        
        bitmapOrg[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),Imgid[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

call like normal array.

```
 Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imgid[index]);
```